# Why is the css is not loading [codeigniter]

Tags: css, codeigniter

Im trying to load a css file with codeigniter framework in my view. I would like to use the base_url, i followed some tuto on the internet but it's still not working.

My controller :

```
    public function clean_art()
{
    $data = array('title' => 'Clean Art');
    $this->load->view('games/clean_art', $data);
    $this->load->helper('url');
}
```

The autoload :

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form','text');;
```

The view :

```
<link type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/views/styles/cleanArt.css">
```

The skeleton of codeigniter :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create assets directory outside of the application directory then move all css,js,images to assets directory.
Ex:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/css/style.css">
```

It's working for me.

Comment: Good Answer. The reason for moving `assets/*` outside of `application/*` is that the web server will not allow access to `application/*` using http which is what a <link...> needs to do.